# How to get characters from a specific index from a string in java

Tags: java, string, character

Suppose, I have a string

```
String command  = "Close the door";
```

Now, I know the keyword **the door**. But I don't know what has before those two words.
I mean to say - how can I get what has before those two words. 
Here I need to get the word **Close**. How can I achieve this programmatically in java?

Comment: If you are using Apache Commons Lang already, they have StringUtils.substringBefore

Comment: Actually I am not willing to use library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you want a general case, but for the question, just do

```
command.substring(0, command.indexOf("the door"));
```

Comment: I got it. It works. I will mark the answer as correct in 3 minutes. I am unable to post the answer as correct right now.

Comment: I need one more help. Suppose I also don't know the word 'door' also. I need only the word 'the'. In this case how can i get my previous word 'Close'. I mean to say, I only know the middle word. So, how can Iget the first word?I